# redirect blog url to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on wordpress site. I am having url like http://example.com/blog/ it should redirect me to http://example.com. If i write http://example.com/blog/page1 then it should redirect me to http://example.com/blog/page1

I'd tried following code in .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /blog http://example.com/
```

with above code if i enter url http://example.com/blog/ then it is redirecting me to home page but if i enter url http://example.com/blog/page1 then it is showing url as http://example.com/page1 and redirect me to 404 page. I am stuck with this problem from last 2 hours and search with google but not find my solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) would probably be what you're after

Comment: i've tried like this in .htacess RedirectMatch "(.*)\blog$" "http://example.com" but it is not working

Comment: That's because the regex is wrong. That is asking for anything, followed by a backslash (or possibly an escaped b), followed by blog at the end, but from the question, you want to match `/blog/`?

Comment: Try this... RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog$ /

Comment: i've tried this RedirectMatch /blog/? http://example.com it is redirecting all /blog urls to home page

Comment: @devofash tried like this RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog$ http://example.com but it is not working

Comment: You've tried @devofash's idea with what URL?

Comment: i'd tried like this RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog$ http://example.com but it is not working

Comment: Yes, with what URL,what are you putting in your browser address bar?

Comment: i m purtting url like this http://example.com/blog/

Comment: Try `RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog$ /` just tested and it works fine.

Comment: @FatemaKhanum Should definitely be working, just tried it. You might have to clear your cache / incognito or reset your permalinks.

Comment: i m trying in incognito everytime but it is not working

Comment: Wait, SO formatting might be screwing things up. Are you going to `http://example.com/blog` or `http://example.com/blog/`?

Comment: tried both urls but none is working

Comment: Then something else is wrong I reckon given my own tests seem to show these directives work as expected.

Comment: This is my htacess inside blog folder

#This Apache config file was created by Duplicator Installer on 2019-08-26 09:38:51.
#The original can be found in archived file with the name htaccess.orig

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog$ http://example.com



</IfModule>
# END WordPress

can u pls chk and let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Try moving the Redirect to before the rewrites.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks very much for your help